# flexslider2 & bootstrap grid compabaility

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexslider

I have a simple bootstrap grid defined: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6LYv/)

The problem is in bootstrap, we define grid like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    ...
```

But in flexslider2 we need to wrap into `li`, e.g.

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
```

But I want to retain to the use of bootstrap grid as it is responsive and position more easy to control. So, it is possible to remain my grid but to apply flexslide onto it?

I.e. in the flddle, I want 4 & 5 to be hidden at the beginning.

Comment: Flexslider 2 is responsive. Your example is clearly missing something. What is the desired output?

Comment: @Ryan Having done a fiddle for this, Flexslider 2 is going to make all the elements disappear anyway for iteration. Indeed the flexslider is responsive as Carrie Kendall mentioned as, it will stretch to a width of 100% width of it's containing column.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is what you are after, but actually FlexSlider has a "selector" option that allows you to wrap your slides into any element you want:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDKp4/1/)

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  selector: ".slides > div.col-md-4"
});
```

Anyway, maybe Bootstrap styles will interfere with Flexslider (because Flexslider sets the width of the slides when it loads), so not sure if this is a good idea. Probably it's easier to define specific styles for the slides.

Comment: Exactly what was needed. Should have been marked as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem you are encountering, but i have updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6LYv/1/).

You should place the whole flexslider into the column:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img ... />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img ... />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img ... />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```